Cannot sign RPM - fails with error 'gpg: Fatal: passphrase-fd is invalid: Bad file descriptor'
I recently moved from a CentOS 7 virtual development environment to a Rocky 8 virtual environment. Now I am unable to build signed RPM files. The line where the build is having issues and the messages displayed are:
rpm --addsign RPMS/x86_64/receiver-2.1.1-3.x86_64.rpm
gpg: Fatal: passphrase-fd is invalid: bad file descriptor
error: gpg exec failed (2)

Per instructions I found elsewhere, I tried to add the parameter 'passphrase-fd 0' to the call, but this resulted in the following error:
rpm: --passphrase-fd: unknown option

Anyone have any idea what is going on with my RPM build?

I found the place in .rpmmacros file where it was setting --passphrase-fd to 3. I changed it from 3 to 0 and it fixed my problem.
